# WL 5.0.5 EdgeToEdgeList first element not under the header but in the middle of the page

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Using EdgeToEdgeList in the main view works fine, if I go to other view from the first EdgeToEdgeList and in this second view (ScrollableView) there is other EdgeToEdgeList, the items in this second list appear "in the middle of the page", this is with an empty space between the header and the first list item.

Debuging it with firebug the second view, that is a dojox.mobile.ScrollableView, has the css property margin-top set to 115px and position to absolute. In firebug, if I remove the margin-top property and set the position to relative everything is displayed fine.

In WL studio, I'm not able to set this properties because they seem to be overwritten so I set a margin-top: -70px in the second EdgeToEdgeList style.

This is the html:

```
<body id="content" style="display: none;" >
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="view0" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeList" id="mylist" >
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="moveTo:'Carreteras'">Testing</div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="moveTo:'Carreteras'">Testing</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="Carreteras" data-dojo-props="selected:false,scrollDir:'v'" >
        <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" data-dojo-props="label:'Carreteras',back:'Atras',moveTo:'view0',fixed:'top'"></h1>
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.EdgeToEdgeList" id="infoViewContent" style="margin-top: -70px;'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" >Testing1</div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" >Testing1</div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <!--application UI goes here-->
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Repsol.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    <script src="js/adapter.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any hint for displaying everything fine since the beggining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things that can cause this kind of problems:

- The way the dojox/mobile/deviceTheme module is loaded. This module should be loaded using a script tag as explained here: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.html#loading-devicetheme-with-a-script-tag.
- The "display: none" style on the body prevents dojox/mobile from computing sizes correctly at startup. This should be changed to "visibility: hidden".

Changing these two things should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine, I have added <script src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script> before the <title> tag and changed the display: none with visibility: hidden. I will try to report this.